Geometry: Proof: line joining the midpoints of two non-parallel sides of a trapezium is parallel to the base
This is a Grade 11 level geometry proof. What is the standard (simplest) proof for DE is parallel to AB? Would it help if we construct a parallel line QR? Does this give an opportunity to use the mid-point theorem? My intention for this construction was to move line AP to QR so that I can apply the mid-point theorem to QRB triangle. However, we cannot straightway claim DE lines goes throgh the mid-point of QR


SAS, with the angle at C.

Instead of proving that DE passes through the midpoint of QR, I suggest proving D, E and the midpoint of PB are collinear using the midlines of triangles ABP, QBP and the Playfair axiom.


One method is to forget line $DE$ for the time being.
Instead from point $D$, draw a line parallel to $AB$ and let it cut $QB$ at $F$.
Prove that $F$ is the mid-point of $QB$.
From this we can conclude that $E$ and $F$ are the same point.
Consequently $DE$ is the same as $DF$.
$DF||AB \implies DE||AB $ .

Let's name some distances:
\begin{align}
a &= CP\\
b &= PD = AD\\
s &= CQ\\
t &= QE = EB\\
\end{align}
Then by similarity of $CPQ$ and $CAB$,
\begin{align}
\frac{a+2b}{s + 2t}  &= \frac{a}{s}, \text{ so}\\
s(a+2b) &= a(s + 2t) \\
sa + 2sb &= sa + 2at \\
2sb &= 2at \\
sb &= at \\
sb + as &= as + at \\
s(a+b) &= a(s+t) \\
\frac{a+b}{s+t} &= \frac{a}{s}
\end{align}
This last equality tells us that $CDE$ is similar to $CPQ$, hence the angles CPQ and CDE are equal; because PQ and DE make the same angle with the line $CA$, they are parallel.
